# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower' when trying to set scale in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to produce a graph with various variables shown on it. Once I have the first variables, I wish to create a second plot on top, with other values set to a different scale. However, I'm trying to set the second plot scale to a value of type float, to make it easier to compare the values compared to the other y plot scale. This is currently what I'm doing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

strain_amplitude = 0.12


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#Some plotted data

ax2 = ax.twinx()
# Some more plotted data for contrast and comparison

ax2.set_yscale(strain_amplitude)
plt.title('Stress and Strain vs. Cycles')
plt.xlabel('Cycles')
plt.ylabel('Stress')
legend = ax.legend(loc = 'lower right', shadow=True, fontsize = 'small')
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('C0')
plt.show()
```

Please bear in mind that whilst I've set strain_amplitude to a set variable here, it can change based on what graph I'm making. However, this code, produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "", line 200, in <module>
    ax2.set_yscale(strain_amplitude)

  File "C:\Users\murray.ross\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 3938, in set_yscale
    ax.yaxis._set_scale(value, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\murray.ross\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 744, in _set_scale
    self._scale = mscale.scale_factory(value, self, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\murray.ross\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\scale.py", line 630, in scale_factory
    scale = scale.lower()

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

How could I go about fixing this? I can't hardcode the value, so I need it to be of type float in my earlier code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide an error traceback showing which line causes the error.

Comment: Have you checked matplotlib documentation for what arguments `set_yscale` expects?

Comment: Yes, but I'm slightly confused. Should I be performing a `get_transform()`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution I'm looking for. It's not `set_yscale` I wanted, but `set_ylim` I needed. This is my working solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

strain_amplitude = 0.12


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#Some plotted data

ax2 = ax.twinx()
# Some more plotted data for contrast and comparison

ax2.set_ylim(strain_amplitude)
plt.title('Stress and Strain vs. Cycles')
plt.xlabel('Cycles')
plt.ylabel('Stress')
legend = ax.legend(loc = 'lower right', shadow=True, fontsize = 'small')
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('C0')
plt.show()
```

Hopefully this provides some clarity to what I was looking for, for anyone who comes across this question.